# org-gcal: could not parse org.file when org-gcal-fetch

Tags: org-mode, org-gcal

I checked, where the error comes from and it's:

```
(while (re-search-forward org-heading-regexp nil t)
```

where org-heading-regexp is:

```
"^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(.*?\\)\\)?[  ]*$"
```

How does my org file have to look like in order to match this?

Currently the file looks like this:

```
 * test
 * Events was ist das
 * hi
```

The error message is:

```
Org-gcal error: Couldn't parse /home/dave/Dropbox/org/events.org
```

and the backtrace looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Run `org-lint` on your org file. If that doesn't show you anything, post the file (or a reasonable facsimile of it that still elicits the error) by editing your question and adding it. And post the exact error message that you get as well as the backtrace if you get one. You might have to do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` to get a backtrace, but depending on how `org-gcal` handles the error, you might not get one at all. In any case, do as many of the above as you can.

Comment: @NickD can you check again please. It comes from org-gcal

Comment: Use triple backquotes to enclose the contents of the file, so that we can see exactly what it looks like (and don't use images if you can help it). It seems that the file does not have any scheduling information, so I'm not sure what you expect should happen. I get the impression that `org-gcal` errors out because of that. If so, that seems wrong: it should ignore such entries and report perhaps the number of successes.  I would open an issue at the org-gcal github repo. In the meantime, you can try with an entry that *does* have some scheduling information (at least a timestamp).

Comment: You put me on the right path @NickD and you are awesome, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds weird, but after putting (see https://github.com/kidd/org-gcal.el/issues/96)

```
* one
* another
SCHEDULED: <2020-07-15 wed 09:15>
:PROPERTIES:
:calendar-id: jjjjjjjjjjjfuuuk842fdok134@group.calendar.google.com
:ETag:     "7777777777980000"
:ID:       xxxxxxxxxxa4jlcj0v998f4u18/jjjjjjjjjjjfuuuk842fdok134@group.calendar.google.com
:END:
:org-gcal:
:END:
```

and some fetching in my events.org, all appointments were strangely fetched. another was overwritten, so weird, but solved my problem.

Comment: As a matter of good housekeeping, you can accept your own answer: that will close the question as answered, so it doesn't pop up periodically as looking for an answer (as it just did).